# shell script gives error [: !-z: unary operator expected while execute

Tags: terminal, bash, script

I've created a bash script to kill the active process searching by name

#### pkill.sh

```
#~/bin/bash
pro=`ps aux | grep $1 | grep -v sh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ !-z "$pro" ]
then
   echo $1 process is not running
else
  kill -9 $pro
  echo $1 process killed forecfully, process id was $pro.
fi
```

and execute this shell script in terminal ( v 2.8) as following

`sh pkill.sh mongod`

the job is done, but it gives the error too

> pkill.sh: line 3: [: !-z: unary operator expected kill: usage: kill
>   [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l
>   [sigspec] mongod process killed forecfully, process id was .

why this script gives an error?

I tried with

`if[[ !z "$pro ]]`

but no help.

Please tell me how to write exactly valid bash script

Comment: Consider using shellcheck.net to assist finding issues with your shell script.

Answer (score 4):

There are three issues I can see:

- The first line should be `#!/bin/bash` (which together with `chmod pkill.sh` will allow you to run `./pkill.sh mongod` directly)
- Whitespace is important in `bash`, try `[ ! -z "$pro" ]` :-)
- `-z` tests for an empty string, so `! -z` tests for a non-empty one. Ignoring for a moment that `-n` does the same thing: shouldn't you call `kill` if the string is non-empty?

PS: Also, using `pgrep` or even `pkill` instead of the pipes will make things a lot easier here.

Comment: Thank you for quick help . Can you please provide syntax for `pgrep` and `pkill` are these inbuilt commad do the same thing?

Comment: @pro.mean, In Terminal i.e. `man command`, e.g., `man pkill`

Comment: @pro.mean Basically `pkill -9 mongod` :-)